# How to get the mean value of a column depending on another column in R and add a new column based on if the value is bigger or smaller than the mean

Tags: r, if-statement, aggregate

| inst | ID | time_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 136 |
| 1 | 1 | 245 |
| 2 | 1 | 64 |
| 3 | 1 | 510 |
| 0 | 14 | 115 |
| 1 | 14 | 491 |
| 2 | 14 | 186 |
| 3 | 14 | 265 |
| 0 | 4 | 131 |
| 1 | 4 | 300 |
| 2 | 4 | 254 |
| 3 | 4 | 284 |

I have instance, ID and time spent columns. I want to add a column called "score" and give "0" or "1" values if  the fish(represented by ID) spends more than 50% of its total time it is 1, else 0. How can I do this in R?

I used aggregate function:
aggregate(B ~ fish_ID, data = allBlue, mean)
and found the mean of each individual. Here I gave some piece of my data as an example. I have a quite a big data set and I would appreciate your recommendations! Thanks.

Comment: So what is the desired output for this sample input. Are all the scores in this example 0?

Comment: The overall mean is 248.41 so the desired outcome is a column with scores of 0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1. Because the values for B_time are greater than mean value and it gets a score of 1. Here is an small example. I want to apply this in my data set and it is quite big. It would be helpful to know if there is a code which can do this calculation for every row and add a new column with scores belonging to that ID and inst.@MrFlick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do these types of operations with dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(score = if_else(time_B> mean(time_B), 1, 0))
#     inst    ID time_B score
#    <int> <int>  <int> <dbl>
#  1     0     1    136     0
#  2     1     1    245     1
#  3     2     1     64     0
#  4     3     1    510     1
#  5     0    14    115     0
#  6     1    14    491     1
#  7     2    14    186     0
#  8     3    14    265     1
#  9     0     4    131     0
# 10     1     4    300     1
# 11     2     4    254     1
# 12     3     4    284     1
```

The idea is that we take the mean per group and compare each value to that mean.

Tested with

```
dd <- data.frame(
  inst = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L), 
  ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
  time_B = c(136L, 245L, 64L, 510L, 115L, 491L, 186L, 265L, 131L, 300L, 254L, 284L)
)
```

Comment: I think, there is missunderstanding. I found it hard to explain. It is my mistake. For example; the mean time spent is 248.42  => mean(dd$time_B). So it has to give a score of "1" for inst 3, ind 1 and for inst 1 and ind 14 and so on. Since the time_B value for this individuals for this intances is greater than the overall mean(248.42).

Comment: @Balina I've updated the code based on your new definition.